# C++11: Trying to create vector of fstreams

Tags: c++, c++11, std, fstream, stdvector

I'm trying to do the following:

```
std::vector< std::fstream > filelist;

while( condition ) {
    fstream f( filename );
    // Do some stuff with f
    f.seekg( 0, std::ios_base::beg );
    filelist.push_back( std::move( f ) );
}
```

However, this is going ka-boom when I try to compile it.  I know that streams are not supposed to be copy-able in C++11, but they should be move-able, right?  I'm feeling like there's something I'm missing here.

Oh, and I am using g++ 4.8.1 with the --std=c++11 option

Comment: Compiled for me under VS2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This particular feature is still not available in gcc 4.8. It should compile fine in clang and VS2012.

Comment: OK, so g++-4.8.1 doesn't yet support the move constructors in streams.  So, I guess I'll try using a std::vector<std::unique_ptr<std::fstream >> instead.